# How to use VGA & HDMI port on my laptop?

Tags: laptop, multiple-monitors, hdmi, vga

I have a VGA and a HDMI port on my laptop like that:

[image]

If I plugin a VGA cable there is no space for a HDMI cable anymore:

[image]

[image]

I did not find slim versions of VGA or HDMI cable. Is there any chance that I may use both ports at the same time, or do I have to buy a new laptop for that?

Comment: Despite my answer below, I'm not actually certain what you're asking us. Do you want us to advise how to rearrange the geometry of the connectors? Do you want us to find an accessory that will allow both these connectors (that's off-topic, we don't recommend hardware)? Do you want us to recommend you buy a new computer (also off topic, we don't recommend hardware)? Basically, at face value it seems you're asking us to confirm what is already evident: That your computer is engineered in a way that appears sub-optimal to your needs/desires.

Comment: Could you clarify what, precisely, you are trying to accomplish and what you're finding yourself unable to learn/do/solve that you believe we may be able to assist with? What does the "right solution" look like in your mind's eye?

Comment: It's very possible that your laptop _cannot_ output to both at the same time... so trying to fit both connections may be fruitless. What processor / graphics does it have?

Comment: Laptop make and model?

Comment: @Appleoddity its HP 350 G2

Comment: @music2myear I was asking if its somehow possible to use 2 monitors on this laptop. I was able to cut-away the right side of the VGA cable and it works. Sorry if my question was unclear. I had no certain answer in mind, I was just asking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could always try using a [dremel](https://www.dremel.com/documents/20812/42772/Rotary+Tool/83d1079e-8fd3-4b4b-b7ad-56f4efcfdb2c?t=1458897223000) or another tool to cut away some of the right side of your VGA connector. The right and left sides of VGA cables are so wide because they're designed with screws to more securely attach to monitors, but if you plan on just using this VGA cable for your laptop cutting away the excess plastic could work.

I have to use a small kitchen knife to strip away the excess material on my headphones every time I buy new ones. The male headphone jack doesn't fit with my phone's case unless I cut away some of the plastic.

Like the above answer said, however, make sure this is just an instance of "sloppy engineering" and not an intentional feature because of your laptop's GPU limitations.

Comment: This is definitely the way to go. Unless you go for a new laptop.

Comment: Lol it actually worked to cut it with a knife.

Answer (score 2):

Unless you can find cables that fit together, then no, there's no way.

This may be engineered this way on purpose as the laptop may not be capable of driving three total screens with its GPU. Or it could be sloppy engineering where they simple did a "good enough" job.

The maximum pixels that can be pushed is typically a published specification for any given GPU, and should be found on the support site for that GPU. This would give you a clue as to which of the above reasons is the real one.

BUT, this is only a surmise, a guess. There is no way that we can tell you for certain WHY the laptop is built this way, nor is there any way we can advise you to adjust the geometry of the outputs to fit additional connectors.

Answer (score 0):

There are small connector HDMI cables, but not slim enough for when the VGA plug is that much in the way.  There are VGA cables with standoff screw connectors you can remove, so that you could barely fit the HDMI cable in there.  You might even be able to do a physical hack and remove one of the VGA cable's sides, but I don't suggest it.

I suspect that the laptop might not even be able to handle that many video connections at once anyway.  When the maker was designing / testing the laptop, they would not go to any lengths to test / make it work for a physically impossible port configuration.